# (Yii2) the page that you are looking for used information.....?

Tags: browser, yii2

my simple **view file**

```
<?php 
 use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
?>
<?php ActiveForm::begin()?>

 <?=Html::submitButton('something')?>

 <?php ActiveForm::end()?
```

Clicked the button. After I reload the page and browser shows me 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYVra.jpg)

So how can I remove this?

Comment: added `die()`...after click the page is blank. I found other way  `if (Yii::$app->request->post('submit')==='my_value') {
       echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";                                              
 exit();
   }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem happen when  you submit data in a form and then  refresh the page
Browsers should stop this, or at least prompt if you want to resend the data,
but the best way to prevent this from happening is submit the data .. and manage the submit properly.

In you case your submit repeat the index action because you don't manage  proper the action code 
(all you're being made does not produce the creation of a new model to be complete so as not prroduce displaying a result.
 or any other action ..
 your code continues to call the same action that produces post calling for action and so on)

try adding a simple die()  or a render for another  view

```
public function actionIndex()
{
   if (Yii::$app->request->post('submit')==='my_value') {
      echo "Button my_value Clicked";
      die(); // or render a proper view  
   } 
   return $this->render('index');
}
```

Comment: added `die()`...after click the page is blank.

Comment: I found other way  `if (Yii::$app->request->post('submit')==='my_value') { echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>"; exit(); }` But there must be better way.

Comment: depend on what you want ... the fact that now the alert is not show .. mean that effectively  you wasrepeat the  calling of the same action.. What is showed after  the echo depend on what you want ..

Comment: Can you answer? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43567773/yii2-variable-not-working-from-post)

Answer (score 0):

This is basic browser behavior. Your form is doing a POST request and obviously when you try to refresh it will ask for this. Even if you write a basic html page without yii, you will still have this.