# (Yii2) Variable not working from post

Tags: post, yii, yii2

**This is my simple index.php file**

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
$this->title = 'Qwert';
?>
<?php $variable=1; //that variable
$f=ActiveForm::begin() ?>

<?php
if($variable==1){
    echo Html::submitButton('First Button',['name'=>'b','value'=>1])."<br/>";
}else{
    echo Html::submitButton('Second Button',['name'=>'b','value'=>2]);}

if(Yii::$app->request->post('b')==='1' ) {$variable=2;}
if(Yii::$app->request->post('b')==='2' ) {$variable=1;} ?>

<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

So I want to after click **First** button it appears **Second**. Where is my mistake?

Comment: The php code is evaluated server side ... so the content of post is available after the commit is execute and the related action is invoke .. and this not client side  .. if you need  an interactive server side  you should look at ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my **Controller**, I have to add return.

```
 if(Yii::$app->request->post('b')==='1' ) {$variable=2; return $this->render('index');}
if(Yii::$app->request->post('b')==='2' ) {$variable=1;return $this->render('index');}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do the request in your controller and do some ajax in your view.

Answer (score 0):

Keep bellow statements after `$variable` declaration.

```
  if(Yii::$app->request->post('b')==='1' ) {$variable=2;}
  if(Yii::$app->request->post('b')==='2' ) {$variable=1;}
```

Like

```
  $variable=1;
  if(Yii::$app->request->post('b')==='1' ) {$variable=2;}
  if(Yii::$app->request->post('b')==='2' ) {$variable=1;}
```

Comment: Are you submitting the form to same page?